# htaccess blog feed redirect

Tags: xml, .htaccess, redirect

i'm trying to get my old blogger blog feed URL (/blog/atom.xml) to redirect to my new blog feed URL (/blog/feed). A regular 301 redirect didn't work, and the advice given on the wordpress site, which is:

```
RewriteRule ^oldfeed.php(.*)? /wordpress/?feed=newfeed [QSA]
```

isn't quite cutting it either - probably because i'm not sure how to adjust the code for oldfeed to accomodate a directory. or for some other reason entirely!

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks very much,

kb

Answer (score 0):

Where does the oldfeed.php come from? You said you wanted to move /blog/atom.xml to /blog/feed.  You could do the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/blog/atom.xml$ $1/blog/feed [R=301]
```

if the /blog/atom.xml and /blog/feed is at your site root (doesn't have anything else in front of it). you can simplify to just:

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/atom.xml$ /blog/feed [R=301]
```